# filebeat.yml.rpmnew or filebeat.yml

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I installed recently filebeat, and I would like to edit the yml file to specify this input:

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- input_type: log
paths:
- /path/*.xml
# scan_frequency: 60s
document_type: message
multiline.pattern: '^<measInfo'
multiline.negate: true
multiline.match: after
```

I should edit the file filebeat.yml or filebeat.yml.rpmnew?

When I edit filebeat.yml I get this message error :

```
filebeat.service - filebeat
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/filebeat.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Thu 2018-07-19 11:35:40 CEST; 2s ago
Docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/index.html
Process: 4695 ExecStart=/usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml -path.home /usr/share/filebeat -path.config /etc/filebeat -path.data /var/lib/filebeat -path.logs /var/log/filebeat (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 4695 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```